# Communicating between React and Asp.net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs

I am getting this error when i try and connect my react project to my asp.net core 3 back end

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

I have up this is my startup method ConfigureServices

```
   services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
        });
```

And I have also put this is the startup config method aswell

```
 app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
```

Comment: how are you hosting the .netcore webapp? Are you running the app via command line / vs debugger or are you using IIS?

Comment: Your policy label added in `AddCors` is different than the policy label that's being (attempted to be) added in `UseCors`

Comment: I am running the application with f5 for the backend. I can hit it with postman and get the correct values returned.

Answer (score 0):

Add these:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look right what you did. The name of your cors policy and cors policy you use are not same. It has to be same. Should be:

```
app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
```

Or what ever your cors policy name.

But also allowing any origins are dangerous. It is better you specified with origin can access this api.
I give an example:

```
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                          builder =>
                          {
                              builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                                  "http://www.contoso.com");
                          });
    });

    // services.AddResponseCaching();
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

And than :

```
 app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

More information you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Changed it and now i get this.The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the CORS policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported

Comment: @gkkkab try with example I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues .

Once was as describe above.
The second is that you have to use https instead of http.